# Calculate Matrix: difference between routing mode car and truck?

Tags: here-api

I am using HERE Calculate Matrix API to calculate matrix for 2 different types of transport (CAR and TRUCK with limited weight to 3.5 T).
Can you please explain what are the differences between these two transport type? I can't calculate matrix for truck despite that in the city there aren't any truck restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

"The routing mode determines how the route is calculated. Matrix calculation is limited to transport types car, carHOV, truck and pedestrian."

So basically, if your vehicule is a Truck, the API is gonna take into account roads where Trucks are allowed to access. Same for cars, cars will obviously have more liberty than trucks so maybe the route will be shorter.